# Bind byte buddy method delegation only to methods with annotated parameters

Tags: java, hibernate-validator, byte-buddy

I want to decorate existing objects so that method calls are automatically validated. I already managed to delegate method call to an interceptor that calls Hibernate validator and so far it works fine:

```
public class HibernateBeanValidator implements BeanValidator{

    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();

    @Override
    public <T> T addMethodValidation(T object) {
        ExecutableValidator executableValidator = factory.getValidator().forExecutables();

        Class<? extends T> dynamicType = (Class<? extends T>)new ByteBuddy()
                .subclass(object.getClass())
                .method(isPublic()).intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new ValidationInterceptor(object, executableValidator)).andThen(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE))
                .make()
                .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
                .getLoaded();

        try {
            T validatedObject = dynamicType.newInstance();
            return  validatedObject;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static class ValidationInterceptor {

        private final Object validatedObject;
        private final ExecutableValidator executableValidator;

        public <T> ValidationInterceptor(T object, ExecutableValidator executableValidator) {
            this.validatedObject = object;
            this.executableValidator = executableValidator;
        }

        public void validate(@Origin Method method, @AllArguments Object[] arguments)
                throws Exception {
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = executableValidator.validateParameters(validatedObject, method, arguments);
            if(! constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ValidationException(constraintViolations);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I would like to improve is to bind method calls only to methods that have at least one parameter annotated with a constraint annotation, such as:

```
class Echo {
    public String repeat(@NotNull String word) { /* should bind validation here */
        return word;
    }

    public String notAnnotated(String word) { /* should not bind validation */
        return word;
    }
}
```

How could I specify an ElementMatcher in Byte Buddy so that it would bind only to methods with parameters annotated with annotations that are annotated with @Constraint, such as @NotNull (taken from javax.validation.constraints):

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface NotNull {

    String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    /**
     * Defines several {@link NotNull} annotations on the same element.
     *
     * @see javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
     */
    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {

        NotNull[] value();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by implementing a custom `ElementMatcher` which is used to identify methods to be intercepted. Currently, you are using the predefined `isPublic()` interceptor which does not consider annotations but only the `public` modifier of a method. As the predefined annotations can be chained, you can build a suitable matcher as follows:

```
isPublic().and(hasParameter(hasAnnotation(nameStartsWith("javax."))))
```

Of course, you can simply implement your own matchers without using the predfined ones.

Answer (score 0):

Actually instead of just checking for an annotation out of the `javax.validation.constraints` namespace, it is probably better to use the Bean Validation meta data API. Constraints do not need to come from this namespace, but can also originate from Hibernate Validator (`org.hibernate.validator.constraints`) or be a custom constraint. A possible implementation of `ElementMatcher` which makes use of the meta data API could look like this:

public static class BeanValidationMatcher implements ElementMatcher {

```
private static final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

@Override
public boolean matches(Object target) {
    // handle different descriptors and potentially use generic MethodDescription
    if ( !( target instanceof MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod methodDescription = (MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod) target;
    Method method = methodDescription.getLoadedMethod();

    boolean isGetter = ReflectionHelper.isGetterMethod( method );

    boolean needsValidation;
    BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor = validator.getConstraintsForClass( method.getDeclaringClass() );
    if ( isGetter ) {
        needsValidation = isGetterConstrained( method, beanDescriptor );
    }
    else {
        needsValidation = isNonGetterConstrained( method, beanDescriptor );
    }

    return needsValidation;
}

private boolean isNonGetterConstrained(Method method, BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor) {
    return beanDescriptor.getConstraintsForMethod( method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes() ) != null;
}

private boolean isGetterConstrained(Method method, BeanDescriptor beanDescriptor) {
    String propertyName = ReflectionHelper.getPropertyName( method );
    PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor = beanDescriptor.getConstraintsForProperty( propertyName );
    return propertyDescriptor != null && propertyDescriptor.findConstraints()
            .declaredOn( ElementType.METHOD )
            .hasConstraints();
}
```

}